# Selecting date range when date is formatted as dd/mm/YYYY

Tags: mysql, sql

The dates in my database are stored as dd/mm/YYYY

How can I construct a simple mySQL query to pull dates within a certain range:

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM metric WHERE date BETWEEN '31/01/2016' AND '01/02/2017'
```

Comment: why did you not store those as standard/built-in mysql dates (functions)? rather than what appears to be varchar - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html - now you've got your work cut out and makes it all that much more harder to query.

Comment: If you're not too far into your project, it's not too late to turn back and I suggest you do. You're making it much harder than it should be.

Comment: `SELECT 2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_to_date` but remember that now the server can't use index on the date column if any.

```
select *
from metric
where str_to_date(date,'%d/%m/%Y') between '2016-01-31'
        and '2017-02-01'
```

It's better to store the date as date or if string then in standard format yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

1. Update all the columns that hold a date as a string to a date column

   ```
   UPDATE metric SET `dateColumn` = str_to_date(`dateColumn`,'%d/%m/%Y');
   ```
2. Alter table

   ```
   ALTER TABLE metric MODIFY `dateColumn` DATE;
   ```
3. Modify your code to insert valid dates to mysql
4. Use built in mysql date functions for your task

   ```
   SELECT * FROM metric WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-01-31' AND '2017-02-01'
   ```

Comment: True. I'm suspecting though that they might be getting their data from a datepicker or similar which is formatted that way, which is probably why they're using a possible varchar as a type; not suggested for sure and makes it that much harder to query later on.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that too - however, one should alter the data from the datepicker. You know how powerful mysql's date functions are @Fred-ii- so I thought I'd better propose their usage.

Comment: Exactly. Like I told them in a comment under their question; it's not too late to change their method if they're not too far into their project.

Comment: Having a look at another of their questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/41103730/1415724 which contains `"date=date_format(curdate(), '%d/%m/%Y')"` - it seems that they appear to be too far into their project to alter their db. I often think of "what stands to be ahead of me", whether it's code or "life/every day stuff" related. Oh well, they have enough to keep going I guess.

Comment: Oh dear... Yeah, that's one of the reasons I started to read the documentation before I develop a project for two years. @Fred-ii-